# Trying to add a class to an img in html using js but can't see it appear in the Google devTools

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the full js for the project:

```js
let image = document.querySelectorAll('img');

 const addActiveClass = () =>{
         removeActiveClass();
         image.forEach(i =>{
             i.classList.add('active');
         })
     }
 
 const removeActiveClass = () =>{
     image.forEach(i =>{
         i.classList.remove('active');
     })
 }
 
 image.forEach(i =>{
     i.addEventListener('click', addActiveClass());
 })
```

```css
> The CSS 

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Mulish:ital,wght@1,300&display=swap');

*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius:50px;
    margin:0;

    font-family: 'Mulish', sans-serif;
    color:white;
}

html{
    height:100vh;
}

body{
    min-height:100%;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
}

.container{
    display:flex;
    min-height:90vh;
    width:90vw;
}

.scrn{
    display:flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    align-items:flex-start;
    justify-content:flex-end;
    flex:0.5;
    color:#fff;
    padding:5px;
}

.scrn h3{
    position:absolute;
    padding: 2%;
    word-break:break-all;
}

.scrn img{
    position:relative;
    max-width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    object-fit:cover;
    transition: flex 0.7s ease-in;
    cursor:pointer;
}

img .active {
    visibility:hidden;
}

> And the HTML
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Expanding Cards</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon " href="#">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="scrn ">
            <img class="img world" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558979158-65a1eaa08691?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80">
            <h3>Explore the World</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="scrn">
            <img onclick = "addActiveClass()" class="img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1572276596237-5db2c3e16c5d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80">
            <h3>Wild Forest</h3>

        </div>
        <div class="scrn">
            <img class="img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1507525428034-b723cf961d3e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1353&q=80">
            <h3>Sunny Beach</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="scrn">
            <img class="img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1551009175-8a68da93d5f9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1351&q=80">
            <h3>City on Winter</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="scrn">
            <img class="img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1549880338-65ddcdfd017b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80">
            <h3>Mountains</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

> I'm trying to dynamically add a class to an image in HTML, by adding an Event Listener so that when it gets clicked , the class is added to the image's classList
> When I click the image i can't see that the class 'active' has been added to the classList of the image like 'img world active'
> I've inserted the whole code of my project above
> I would greatly appreciate any help !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The addEventListener method takes a function as its second argument. Your problem here is that instead of giving the addEventListener method the function reference like this: `i.addEventListener('click', addActiveClass);`, you directly called it like this: `i.addEventListener('click', addActiveClass());`.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/api/eventlistener

Keep in mind that your code will actually add the class "active" to all the images, because in your addActiveClass function you iterate over all of them and add the class "active". I assume that you only want the class "active" on the image you recently clicked on. In this case we just take the event argument which is passed by the addEventListener method and add the class to its target like this: `e.target.classList.add('active');`

To use the element.class selector you have to write the selector whithout whitespace like this: `element.class` instead of `element .class`.
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_class.asp

```js
let image = document.querySelectorAll('img');

 const addActiveClass = (e) =>{
         removeActiveClass();
         e.target.classList.add('active');
     }
 
 const removeActiveClass = () =>{
     image.forEach(i =>{
         i.classList.remove('active');
     })
 }
 
 image.forEach(i =>{
     i.addEventListener('click', addActiveClass);
 })
```

```css
> The CSS 

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Mulish:ital,wght@1,300&display=swap');

*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius:50px;
    margin:0;

    font-family: 'Mulish', sans-serif;
    color:white;
}

html{
    height:100vh;
}

body{
    min-height:100%;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
}

.container{
    display:flex;
    min-height:90vh;
    width:90vw;
}

.scrn{
    display:flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    align-items:flex-start;
    justify-content:flex-end;
    flex:0.5;
    color:#fff;
    padding:5px;
}

.scrn h3{
    position:absolute;
    padding: 2%;
    word-break:break-all;
}

.scrn img{
    position:relative;
    max-width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    object-fit:cover;
    transition: flex 0.7s ease-in;
    cursor:pointer;
}

img.active {
    visibility:hidden;
}

> And the HTML
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Expanding Cards</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon " href="#">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="scrn ">
            <img class="img world" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558979158-65a1eaa08691?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80">
            <h3>Explore the World</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="scrn">
            <img class="img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1572276596237-5db2c3e16c5d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80">
            <h3>Wild Forest</h3>

        </div>
        <div class="scrn">
            <img class="img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1507525428034-b723cf961d3e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1353&q=80">
            <h3>Sunny Beach</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="scrn">
            <img class="img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1551009175-8a68da93d5f9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1351&q=80">
            <h3>City on Winter</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="scrn">
            <img class="img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1549880338-65ddcdfd017b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80">
            <h3>Mountains</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```